# gl_Normal not calculating correctly

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

When I try and use gl_Normal in my GLSL vertex shader, it stays a vec3 with a 0 for the x and y components, and a 1.0 for the z component. Is there some openGL statement that enables normal calculation? I am trying to acomplish a simple shading program, I have imported a model into the world, but for some reason the built-in variable gl_Normal is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're supposed to pass the vertex normals together with vertex positions, using `glNormalPointer` (or `glNormal`).

I suggest to import your model in a 3D modelling tool (like Blender) - it can generate the normal vectors automatically for you. Then just save it and import in your application with normals.

Comment: No, they aren't calculated automatically. You can try to make them procedurally, but using a tool like Blender should be better and allows you to control the result. You might also want to duplicate some vertices and edges to obtain sharp creases at some places. Creating normals is mostly automated, but generally needs supervision of the modeller.

Comment: And when you have them, like I told you, pass them together using `glNormal3f`. (You'll probably want to switch to buffer objects, `glVertexPointer` and `glNormalPointer` soon for performance)

Comment: Wow, I was really confused. I actually didn't know glNormal3f existed. Thanks again!